# Windows 10 virtual machine issue

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I downloaded a Windows 10 .iso file from microsoft site to run in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine (media creation tool), then I went on to setting it up.. No problems there. The issue arose when I powered down the VM, started it up later, and it asked me to start all over again (choosing language, region etc.).
Naturally this lead me to conclude that I was booting it live (or something of that nature). How do I prevent the VM asking for a reinstallation??

Thanks In Advance.
R.

Comment: Unmount the .iso from the vm.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: The same way you mounted the .iso to install Windows in the first place. Do the opposite. It’s in the VM hardware settings. The .iso is a virtual cd-rom.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I managed to remove the disk and got the outcome I wanted.

Comment: Might be worth it to post an answer to close the loop.